# SPFx show list items in a drop down (Not in web-part property)

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, spfx, sharepointframework, pnp-js

I am quite new to SPFx and trying to build a web part, In my web part I would have a Dropdown button and the Dropdown values would come from a SharePoint list. I want to use react and pnpjs. how do I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could know how to retrieve items in spfx in this video: [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nsGhYjfRsw)

My test code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './TaxonomyPopulator.module.scss';
import { ITaxonomyPopulatorProps } from './ITaxonomyPopulatorProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import { taxonomy, ITerm, ITermSet, ITermStore } from '@pnp/sp-taxonomy';
import { ISPListCustomerItem } from './ICustomers';
import { ClassCustomer } from './ClassCustomer';
import pnp, { Web } from 'sp-pnp-js';

export default class TaxonomyPopulator extends React.Component<ITaxonomyPopulatorProps,any> {
  constructor(props:ITaxonomyPopulatorProps,any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      titles:[]
    };
  }



  public render(): React.ReactElement<ITaxonomyPopulatorProps> {

    return (
      <div >
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>
            <div className={ "ms-Grid" }>
            <div className={ "ms-Grid-row" }>
            <select>
             {

               this.state.titles.map((element) =>{                
               return <option>{element}</option>              
               })

            }

             </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }  
  public componentDidMount() {
    this._getListCustomerData();   
  }
  private _getListCustomerData():void
  {    
    var titles:Array<any> = [];
    let web = new Web(this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);
      web.lists.getByTitle('test2').items.get().then
      ((response)=>{
        let customerCollection=response.map(item=>{
          titles.push(item.Title);
        });       
        this.setState({titles});
      }

      )
  }
}
```

Test result:

[image]

I show all title column in list ‘test2’,you could modify the code as you need.

Comment: I followed your step but i am getting an error.

   Property 'context' does not exist on type 'Readonly<IGetlistitemsReactProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 0):

Finally! it worked. Here is my code

```
import * as React from "react";
import styles from "./Spfxdropdowm.module.scss";
import { ISpfxdropdowmProps } from "./ISpfxdropdowmProps";
import { escape } from "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset";
import pnp from "sp-pnp-js";
import { ClassCustomer } from "./ClassCustomer";
import { ISPListCustomerItem } from "./ICustomers";
import { taxonomy, ITerm, ITermSet, ITermStore } from "@pnp/sp-taxonomy";
import { IStackTokens, Stack } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Stack";
import {
  Dropdown,
  DropdownMenuItemType,
  IDropdownStyles,
  IDropdownOption,
} from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Dropdown";

const dropdownStyles: Partial<IDropdownStyles> = {
  dropdown: { width: 300 },
};
const options: IDropdownOption[] = [
  { key: "apple", text: "Apple" },
  { key: "banana", text: "Banana" },
  { key: "orange", text: "Orange" },
  { key: "grape", text: "Grape" },
  { key: "broccoli", text: "Broccoli" },
  { key: "carrot", text: "Carrot" },
  { key: "lettuce", text: "Lettuce" },
];
const stackTokens: IStackTokens = { childrenGap: 20 };

var items: IDropdownOption[] = [];

export interface IReactGetItemsState {
  items: IDropdownOption[];
}

export default class GetlistitemsReact extends React.Component<
  ISpfxdropdowmProps,
  any
> {
  public constructor(props: ISpfxdropdowmProps, any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
    };
  }

  public async componentDidMount(): Promise<void> {
    // get all the items from a sharepoint list
    var reacthandler = this;
    pnp.sp.web.lists
      .getByTitle("Division")
      .items.select("Title")
      .get()
      .then(function (data) {
        for (var k in data) {
          items.push({ key: data[k].Title, text: data[k].Title });
        }
        reacthandler.setState({ items });
        console.log(items);
        return items;
      });
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<ISpfxdropdowmProps> {
    return (
      <Stack tokens={stackTokens}>
        <Dropdown
          placeholder="Select an option"
          label="Division"
          options={this.state.items}
          styles={dropdownStyles}
        />
      </Stack>
    );
  }
}
```